# how to use datagram socket class in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to know how can i use the datagram socket class which is provided by java.net package in blackberry. I tried to use it but it the compiler is not able to find the java.net package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've confused Java-SE with Java-ME.  BlackBerry devices do not run the full desktop Java.  The language is close to Java 1.3, which was released around the year 2000.  The APIs available are intentionally cut down, to save on device storage.   Specifically, it looks like you want to use [java.net.DatagramSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html), but as you've noticed, that isn't available for Java-ME BlackBerry devices. Instead, you should use the [Connector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html) class to create a [DatagramConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/javax/microedition/io/DatagramConnection.html)